# Why statue's face is hidden like this?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-covenant

In Alien Convenant, this statue looks like greek to me, but it is hidden like this.

[image]

Why statue's face is hidden like this?

Comment: Note that statue is a copy of Michelangelo's famous [David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_(Michelangelo)); Italian Renaissance, not Greek.

Comment: good point, thank you, I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statue is based on Michealangelo's  David, an Italian renaissance sculpture. Its inclusion would appear to be a case of foreshadowing and also a call back to the ending of Prometheus. By obscuring the head, the torso of the statue takes on a resemblance to an Engineer's because of the large scale and off-white colour. Later in the film, the Engineers are destroyed by David.  By obscuring the head, we are reminded of David's decapitation at the end of the previous film and are given a clue that the Engineers can or will be destroyed.

An article on the Alien-covenant.com forum theorises that David takes his name from the biblical character that this statue is based on. In the bible, David battles and kills Goliath, a much larger opponent. You can read the whole article [here](https://www.alien-covenant.com/topic/48358), but it is worth noting that it is fan theory and not word of God.

Ridley Scott, the director of the film, talks at length in the commentary for Covenant about how we have nothing to fear from AI unless we give them emotions, which David has. David becomes resentful of his position as a servant of humans. He sees himself as more intelligent or better than humans, and essentially rebels against humanity and his creator. As he is one robot against many humans, you could certainly take it as a David and Goliath situation, but as far as I can recall he does not specifically discuss the statue.

The TV tropes website does go some way to corroborating these theories mentioning that:

> David is named for Michaelangelo's sculpture of the same name. He also has the flayed corpse of an Engineer in his laboratory, posed in the same manner as the statue.

Comment: "*Optical perceptors stopped and identified Michelangelo’s statue of David, fashioned from Carrara marble. It-he could see the slight rises and indentations made by the cold chisel. A copy, perhaps, but one infused with real creativity. Not necessarily a contradiction. He walked over to it. “David,” he said. By Michelangelo di Lodovico Buonarroti Simoni. Finished and installed summer, 1504. “We are David.” It-he held out a hand and made contact with the stone. It was cool, dry, unyielding. Not human, yet so very human. “Beautiful and cold.” “Perfect in every way,” Weyland concurred.*